# SQL-PHP: Assign the value of the calculation from MySQL into PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to use MySQL to calculate the differences of the value:

```
SELECT 
  tour_packages.quantity_total - tour_packages.quantity_used 
  AS slots
FROM tour_packages
```

But how do I set the answer of the calculation into PHP variable? Is this practice even possible?

Comment: In php code, simply access the `slots` key from the result-set obtained after the `query` and `fetch` operations.

Comment: Take a look at [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Sooo... all I've to do are these?

`$calculation = "SELECT tour_packages.quantity_total - tour_packages.quantity_used 
                      AS slots
                      FROM tour_packages";
$resultcalculate = mysqli_query($con, $calculation);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultcalculate);
      $remainingslot = $row['slots'];`

Comment: @MEMYSELF yes. precisely

Comment: I tried, and the php for some reason only echo out the value of quantity_used from database, but not the answer of the calculation.

Comment: @MEMYSELF put them in brackets

Comment: Tried, still the same thing.

Comment: If there's no solution for this I guess I'm forced to use the old fashion way: take the values from the database and assign to the variable specifically, then use php math to calculate the answer.

It's a shame tho, as this could've been easily done in 1 line of SQL query. :/

Comment: Since you don't have a `WHERE` clause, wouldn't you want  `(SUM(tour_packages.quantity_total) - SUM(tour_packages.quantity_used)) AS slots` ?